# Webpack url-loader encodes image url but breaks file Path

Tags: webpack, urlloader

I following this post of how to [setup webpack and url-loader](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/handling-images-e1a2a2c28f8d) can successfully encode the url but the image path is broken and image does not show up. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks for any help you can give.

**webpack.config**

```
{
        test: /\.(gif|png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 1000000,
            name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
          }
        }]
}
```

**index.js**

```
import homeIcon from '../images/image-file.png';
var homeImg = document.getElementById('home');
homeImg.src = homeIcon;
```

**index.html**

**File Structure**

```
src
  js
    index.js
  images
      image-file.png
```

Comment: Is index.js under src?  I think you need: `import homeIcon from './images/image-file.png';` then

Comment: thanks for your reply, The index file is under src > js > index.js I have added this to the files structure